# Netlogo: How to change 0 to blank in BehaviorSpace's spreadsheet.csv file?

Tags: csv, spreadsheet, netlogo

In the notation of BehaviorSpace's spreadsheet.csv file output value, if the output result is 0 notation, 
I want to replace it with blank notation, but I do not know how to do it (it is not posted on netlogo website). 
The mean value of the BehaviorSpace's spreadsheet.csv file output value is automatically generated. 
I do not want to include in the calculation of mean if the data is 0. 
Currently, I am rediscovering the mean by erasing the 0 data in the spreadsheet.csv file by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can do this in Netlogo exactly as you want as it doesn't really deal with NULL, NA, or NAN values. One thing that might work is to build a reporter that reports a string value you can then filter out. For a simple example:

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 10
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    rt random 60 - 30
    fd 1
  ]
  tick
end

to-report mean-y-or-nobody
  let val mean [ycor] of turtles 
  ifelse val > 0 [
    report val 
  ]
  [ report "#N/A"
  ]  
end
```

If you set up an experiment to run this program and report the `mean-y-or-nobody` reporter:

[image]

Your output will be a standard CSV output, but with string "#N/A" values where the zeroes would normally be. For me at least, Excel will automatically ignore those values (some rows hidden in the image):

[image]

If that doesn't work for you, or if you're using different spreadsheet software, at least now you can just find/replace those string values without worrying about replacing other zeroes. Of course, if you are using something like R this would all be unnecessary as you could just replace the zero values with real NA values.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It was very useful.